# Missing functions in my android studio project (kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I started learning Android development with Android Studio,
I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBWyXo-3JGQ&t=3571s) tutorial about creating a Todo list app, which is pretty recent and still it seems like a lot of things have changed.

So i have a few problems:

1. In the tutorial he uses View.apply{}, when i tried it, it says `Unresolved reference: apply` And i haven't found anything about this function online, like it never existed. ([46:50] in the tutorial)
2. He also create a MutableList<> variable and initialize it with mutableListOf(), I created the variable successfully, but I can't find the function mutableListOf(), or similar functions like arrayListOf() and so on. ([59:30] in the tutorial)
3. On the same MutableList<> variable he uses the function removeAll{} to remove all items in the list that match a condition, i don't have that overload, and only have a removeAll() that takes another list and remove matching items. ([57:00] in the tutorial)

2+3 from what i understand suggest that i don't have the kotlin stdlib in the project, but i haven't managed to add it.

This is my build files:

build.gradle for the project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle for the module:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'

}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.todo"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem!

I needed to add this line to the module build file

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

and this line to the project build file

```
ext.kotlin_version= '1.5.30'
```

Aren't does lines supposed to be automatically added on project creation?
At least the kotlin_version because i still don't know why the editor suggested i use 1.5.30.

when i looked online the latest version is 1.5.21 but that didn't work for me.